# Python was working - made no changes - will no longer work. What could have happened?

Tags: python, windows, debugging, python-2.7, typeerror

I have been running the following script in my terminal for the past few days. I have made no changes to it. Previously, it had always been working perfectly, now I have the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetAlexRanking.py", line 193, in <module>
    print("%s:%d" % (p.__class__.__name__, p.get_rank(url
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Here is the code in its entirity. It should be possible to save it in a .py file, run it from terminal shell with the command `python filename.py www.google.com` to print out some traffic stats for Google. This will no longer work for me however. What is the problem here ?

```
import struct
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import httplib
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree

class RankProvider(object):
    """Abstract class for obtaining the page rank (popularity)
from a provider such as Google or Alexa.

"""
    def __init__(self, host, proxy=None, timeout=30):
        """Keyword arguments:
host -- toolbar host address
proxy -- address of proxy server. Default: None
timeout -- how long to wait for a response from the server.
Default: 30 (seconds)

"""
        self._opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        if proxy:
            self._opener.add_handler(urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": proxy}))

        self._host = host
        self._timeout = timeout

    def get_rank(self, url):
        """Get the page rank for the specified URL

Keyword arguments:
url -- get page rank for url

"""
        raise NotImplementedError("You must override get_rank()")


class AlexaTrafficRank(RankProvider):
    """ Get the Alexa Traffic Rank for a URL

"""
    def __init__(self, host="xml.alexa.com", proxy=None, timeout=30):
        """Keyword arguments:
host -- toolbar host address: Default: joolbarqueries.google.com
proxy -- address of proxy server (if required). Default: None
timeout -- how long to wait for a response from the server.
Default: 30 (seconds)

"""
        super(AlexaTrafficRank, self).__init__(host, proxy, timeout)

    def get_rank(self, url):
        """Get the page rank for the specified URL

Keyword arguments:
url -- get page rank for url

"""
        query = "http://%s/data?%s" % (self._host, urllib.urlencode((
            ("cli", 10),
            ("dat", "nsa"),
            ("ver", "quirk-searchstatus"),
            ("uid", "20120730094100"),
            ("userip", "192.168.0.1"),
            ("url", url))))

        response = self._opener.open(query, timeout=self._timeout)
        if response.getcode() == httplib.OK:
            data = response.read()

            element = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(data)
            for e in element.iterfind("SD"):
                popularity = e.find("POPULARITY")
                if popularity is not None:
                    return int(popularity.get("TEXT"))


class GooglePageRank(RankProvider):
    """ Get the google page rank figure using the toolbar API.
Credits to the author of the WWW::Google::PageRank CPAN package
as I ported that code to Python.

"""
    def __init__(self, host="toolbarqueries.google.com", proxy=None, timeout=30):
        """Keyword arguments:
host -- toolbar host address: Default: toolbarqueries.google.com
proxy -- address of proxy server (if required). Default: None
timeout -- how long to wait for a response from the server.
Default: 30 (seconds)

"""
        super(GooglePageRank, self).__init__(host, proxy, timeout)
        self._opener.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; \
GoogleToolbar 2.0.111-big; Windows XP 5.1)")]

    def get_rank(self, url):
        # calculate the hash which is required as part of the get
        # request sent to the toolbarqueries url.
        ch = '6' + str(self._compute_ch_new("info:%s" % (url)))

        query = "http://%s/tbr?%s" % (self._host, urllib.urlencode((
            ("client", "navclient-auto"),
            ("ch", ch),
            ("ie", "UTF-8"),
            ("oe", "UTF-8"),
            ("features", "Rank"),
            ("q", "info:%s" % (url)))))

        response = self._opener.open(query, timeout=self._timeout)
        if response.getcode() == httplib.OK:
            data = response.read()
            match = re.match("Rank_\d+:\d+:(\d+)", data)
            if match:
                rank = match.group(1)
                return int(rank)

    @classmethod
    def _compute_ch_new(cls, url):
        ch = cls._compute_ch(url)
        ch = ((ch % 0x0d) & 7) | ((ch / 7) << 2);

        return cls._compute_ch(struct.pack("<20L", *(cls._wsub(ch, i * 9) for i in range(20))))

    @classmethod
    def _compute_ch(cls, url):
        url = struct.unpack("%dB" % (len(url)), url)
        a = 0x9e3779b9
        b = 0x9e3779b9
        c = 0xe6359a60
        k = 0

        length = len(url)

        while length >= 12:
            a = cls._wadd(a, url[k+0] | (url[k+1] << 8) | (url[k+2] << 16) | (url[k+3] << 24));
            b = cls._wadd(b, url[k+4] | (url[k+5] << 8) | (url[k+6] << 16) | (url[k+7] << 24));
            c = cls._wadd(c, url[k+8] | (url[k+9] << 8) | (url[k+10] << 16) | (url[k+11] << 24));

            a, b, c = cls._mix(a, b, c)

            k += 12
            length -= 12

        c = cls._wadd(c, len(url));

        if length > 10: c = cls._wadd(c, url[k+10] << 24)
        if length > 9: c = cls._wadd(c, url[k+9] << 16)
        if length > 8: c = cls._wadd(c, url[k+8] << 8)
        if length > 7: b = cls._wadd(b, url[k+7] << 24)
        if length > 6: b = cls._wadd(b, url[k+6] << 16)
        if length > 5: b = cls._wadd(b, url[k+5] << 8)
        if length > 4: b = cls._wadd(b, url[k+4])
        if length > 3: a = cls._wadd(a, url[k+3] << 24)
        if length > 2: a = cls._wadd(a, url[k+2] << 16)
        if length > 1: a = cls._wadd(a, url[k+1] << 8)
        if length > 0: a = cls._wadd(a, url[k])

        a, b, c = cls._mix(a, b, c);

        # integer is always positive
        return c

    @classmethod
    def _mix(cls, a, b, c):
        a = cls._wsub(a, b); a = cls._wsub(a, c); a ^= c >> 13;
        b = cls._wsub(b, c); b = cls._wsub(b, a); b ^= (a << 8) % 4294967296;
        c = cls._wsub(c, a); c = cls._wsub(c, b); c ^= b >>13;
        a = cls._wsub(a, b); a = cls._wsub(a, c); a ^= c >> 12;
        b = cls._wsub(b, c); b = cls._wsub(b, a); b ^= (a << 16) % 4294967296;
        c = cls._wsub(c, a); c = cls._wsub(c, b); c ^= b >> 5;
        a = cls._wsub(a, b); a = cls._wsub(a, c); a ^= c >> 3;
        b = cls._wsub(b, c); b = cls._wsub(b, a); b ^= (a << 10) % 4294967296;
        c = cls._wsub(c, a); c = cls._wsub(c, b); c ^= b >> 15;

        return a, b, c

    @staticmethod
    def _wadd(a, b):
        return (a + b) % 4294967296

    @staticmethod
    def _wsub(a, b):
        return (a - b) % 4294967296


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = sys.argv[1]
    providers = (AlexaTrafficRank(), GooglePageRank(),)

    print("Traffic stats for: %s" % (url))
    for p in providers:
        print("%s:%d" % (p.__class__.__name__, p.get_rank(url)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both of your `get_rank` instance methods, you have the line:

```
if response.getcode() == httplib.OK:
```

Then another function-specific `if`. The methods will only `return` a value if both evaluate `True` (plus, in `AlexaTrafficRank`, `element.iterfind("SD")` has to have values); otherwise, they will implicitly `return None`, hence the error you see.

Comment: @jonrharpe Thank you for this. So I can remove the problem simply by removing the highlighted if statement or is there more to it than this? Also, what do you think may have caused it to break out of the blue? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @SimonKiely there is plenty that can go wrong (or just change) when using online resources. I am not saying you should remove the `if`s, but you need to deal with the possibility they won't be `True`, either inside the method or in the caller.